# While copying image using UIPasteboard from a custom keyboard shows a white background while sending

Tags: ios, swift, custom-keyboard, uipasteboard

I have created a custom keyboard with some png images. All of those png images have a transparent/clear background. But when we copy that image and try to send the same in any messaging App, it is showing a white background. If i try some other keyboard Apps, it is working fine without any background.I am using this code:

Please check: [Screenshot with white background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rLkTl.png)
And: [Screenshot without background when sending image from other apps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fP03K.png)

```
let pasteboard = UIPasteboard.general
let pngdata = UIImagePNGRepresentation((button.imageView?.image)!)
let imgg = UIImage(data: pngdata!)!
pasteboard.image = imgg
```

Comment: Have you checked if the UIImagePNGRepresentation((button.imageView?.image)!), provided the proper image without white background.

Comment: Yes, it was fine. I managed to fix the issue by copying the data into pasteboard instead of image.